# Use a container component for nested routes using Next-routes

Tags: reactjs, routes, next.js

I am using Next.js and the next-routes library to create an app for Shopify. I'd like to use a container component to wrap a few routes but I cannot find how to do this in any documentation.

My pages are organized as such:

```
container.js
container/page1.js
container/page2.js
```

and my routes are:

```
module.exports = routes()
.add('container/page1', '/container/page1')
.add('container/page2', '/container/page2/:param')
```

Everything is working properly but I have no idea how to make the page routes go through the container using `{this.props.children}` like with React-Router

Comment: Are these pages inside of the `pages` directory?

Comment: Yes, sorry I should have mentioned everything is inside /pages. I want to use a container so they can share the state of this container but not share it with the rest of the app.

Comment: I can't think of how different pages would share state.  Wouldn't navigating from page1 to page2 reload the container causing you to lose state?

Comment: so the only way to go from page to page and edit the same set of states is to go through Redux or a similar solution?

Comment: I want to think so. I can't think of any other way other than having a persistent state.